# How to store unmatched string from an object using JavaScript / Node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, nodes

I have a little doubt and don't know the solution.

- I have an object and I want to check if string is present or not
- As I have a code to check if string present or not in object a code
- what if string does not match with the value
- As this unmatched value I want to save in database which does not match the `fileName`
- I got my string `fileName` by running for loop code below

```
for (let i = 0; i <= readFileArray.length - 1; i++) {
      for (let j = 0; j < readFileArray[i].length; j++) {
        if (readFileArray[i][j] === comparePathName) {
          let fileName = readFileArray[1][j];
        }
      }
    }
```

so this fileName after running for Loop it can be

```
fileName: Java
fileName: Node JS
fileName: JavaScript
fileName: Asp.net
fileName: Oops
```

and I want to check value of `fileName` is not present in my Object (productDoc)

- for let say my `productDoc` look like this

```
productDoc = [
 {
    id: 1,
    name:Java,
    description: language
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name:JavaScript,
    description: language
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name:Oops,
    description: Subject
  }
]
```

so I want to check every name which is present inside the `productDoc` by my `fileName`

matched value should be store differently and unmatched value stored differently
as I need this unmatched value to store in my database were matched value are already in database

```
matched: Java
matched: JavaScript
matched: Node Js
```

```
unMatched: Asp.net
unMatched: Oops
```

so i can use this value in If else condition

```
if(matched){
updateDocument(matched)
}else{
addDocument(unmatched)
}
```

Comment: what is `fileName` ? string, a number, array , object ?

Comment: its a string @nur

Comment: An example would be helpful. How would you want to match ?

Comment: Ok wait i will update my question

Comment: Hello Nur I have updated the question have a look :)

Comment: Its so simple... create an array of `fileName`... then iterate `productDoc` and check `productDoc.name` was includes in `fileName`.

Comment: Hello @Nur actually i want unmatched value so i can use them to add in my database and the match value to update my database I have updated my question

Comment: Same thing, `var productNames = Array.from(productDoc, item => item.name);` created an array of product name, then filtered by `var unmatched = fileName.filter(filename => !productNames.includes(filename))`;  results: `console.log(unmatched);` does it answer your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I sayed in comments, create an array, then check if it included or not...

```js
var fileName = ["Oops", "Java", "JavaScript", "NodeJs", "ReactJs"],
    productDoc = [{ name: "Java", }, { name: "JavaScript", }, { name: "Oops", }],
    productNames = Array.from(productDoc, item => item.name),
    matched = [],
    unMatched = [];

for (const name of fileName)
    productNames.includes(name) ? matched.push(name) : unMatched.push(name);

console.log({ matched, unMatched });
```

Comment: Hello @nur my `fileName` is not an array as i am runninf for Loop all the values i am getting in `fileName` is string type

Comment: Yup created array of fileName. can i save array in database directly ? i dont know about this

Comment: you don't have to create array of `fileName`. I just use it  for iteration in `for/of` loop...

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this would be to read all the files from a directory using

```
var fileList = [];
path = 'YOUR_PATH_TO_DIRECTORY';

fs.readdirSync(path).forEach(file => {
  
   fileList.push(file);    
   //this will read all the files and save push it in fileList
  
})
```

Then, you can compare the read file names with the array object

```
var matchingValue = [];
var unMatchingValue = [];

for(var i = 0; i < this.productDoc.length; i++)
    {
        for(var j = 0; j < this.fileList.length; j++)
        {
          if(this.productDoc[i].name == this.fileList[j])
          {
            this.matchingValue[i].push(this.productDoc[i].name);

            //this will push the matching element from the productDoc
            //in the new array matchingValue
          }
          else if(this.product[i].name != this.fileList[j])
          {
            this.unMatchingValue[i].push(this.product[i].name);
            
          }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi @Angular i need matched value to update my database 
and unmatched value to be added in database

Comment: @Aakash, I have updated the answer. I haven't tested the code but, it would be something like this.